# How to calculate White-Huber standard errors by hand

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity

I can't see how to replicate the calculation of WH standard errors for heteroscedastic data, as produced by the R packages `sandwich` / `coeftest`. Below is my attempt (coded in `R`):

```
# install.packages("sandwich")
# install.packages("coeftest")
library(sandwich)
library(coeftest)

# Define some heteroscedastic data
    set.seed(1)
    n <- 1000
    x <- runif(n, 0, 1)
    y <- 5*rnorm(n, 0, x*10)

# Show (visually, not statistically) that the data are heteroscedastic
    plot(y~x, col="gray", pch=19, xlab="x", ylab="y parameter")

# HC-estimators using the White estimator the easy way...
    fit <- lm(y~x)
    coeftest(fit, vcov=vcovHC(fit, type="HC0")) # SE = 3.56

# ...and the long way... with an error somewhere along the line...

    x.mat <- matrix(x, ncol=1)
    bread <- solve(t(x.mat) %*% x.mat)
    meat  <- t(x.mat) %*% diag(fit$residuals^2) %*% x.mat
    variance.of.beta <- bread %*% meat %*% bread

# Standard error...
    se <- sqrt(variance.of.beta / n)  
    se

# 0.0686  # ??!
```

Comment: (1) software-related questions are off-topic on this site, (2) please do not **shout**, but rather use normal formatting with leaving bold font and headers for special cases, (3) notice that there is no question in your "question".

Comment: @Tim, this may be a question about how to replicate R's outputted values via explicit calculations (presumably to better understand the nature of HW sandwich SEs). Then it would really be about statistics, not how to code / use R. In addition, I suspect the 'shouting' is due to R's comment character `#` not playing well w/ SEs formatting.

Comment: I have edited the question, such that it is formatted in the way (I think) OP would have wanted it. Also I do not understand the down vote...

Comment: @gung OK, but still there is not question stated in here, just pure R code...

Comment: The question is obviously there, even if not stated

Comment: @Tim, you're right. I just think the question is implied. I edited the title to state what I think the question is. In addition, Repmat's answer is the answer to what I understand the question to be (I originally saw this, commented, & edited from the review queue, before I saw that an answer had been proffered).

Comment: Hi everybody - Just a quick note to say thanks to all of you. No shouting intended... and I guess the bold had appeared, as gung says, because of the formatting - thanks also for editing the title straight off. My bad - sorry, lessons learnt. @Repmat - thanks for the editing (exactly as I meant!) and the correction. Really helpful of you as well. Tim - sorry for the poor formatting, and the lack of Q. Agree, not helpful on my part. Sorry. Thanks everybody, I'll try to do better next time. t

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot the intercept in the x matrix, when you did the calculation. Assume the setup as before:

```
library(sandwich) 

set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
x <- runif(n,0,1)
y <- 5*rnorm(n,0,x*10)

fit <- lm(y ~ x)
sqrt(vcovHC(fit, type="HC0")[2,2]) # SE = 3.56
```

Now for the manual part:

```
# Remember the intercept in the x matrix:
x <- matrix(cbind(1, x), ncol = 2)

bread <- solve(t(x) %*% x)

butter <- t(x) %*% diag(fit$residuals)^2 %*% x

EHW <- bread %*% butter %*% bread

sqrt(EHW[2,2]) # SE = 3.56
```

EDIT: I would like to add that coeftest is not a package itself, but rather a function in the package lmtest.

Comment: Note that the `sandwich` package does not just put "butter" between the two slices of bread but some "meat", see `?sandwich`. Preferences may vary, though, myself being a vegetarian. So butter, cheese, jam, and other fillings should really be supported as well ;-)