# Heteroskedasticity-robust standard errors computation by hands

Tags: regression, standard-error, heteroscedasticity

Consider the following multiple linear regression model
\begin{equation}
y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + ... + \beta_k x_k +u
\end{equation}
If the variance of the error is not constant for any value of the regressors, we have heteroskedasticity and Gauss-Markov assumption of homoskedasticity is violeted, i.e., $Var(u_i|x_{i1},...,x_{ik})= \sigma^2_i$.

A valid estimator of $Var(\hat{\beta}_j)$, under Gauss-Markov with homoskedasticity not necessarily holding, is
\begin{equation}
 \widehat{Var}(\hat{\beta}_j) = \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \hat{r}^2_{ij} \hat{u}^2_i}{RSS^2_j} = \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \hat{r}^2_{ij} \hat{u}^2_i}{[TSS_j (1-R^2_j)]^2}
 \label{varbeta3}
\end{equation}
where $\hat{r}_{ij}$ denotes the $i$ residual from regressing $x_j$ on all the other independent variables, and $RSS_j$ is the residual sum of squares from this regression. Also, $TSS_j$ is the total sample variation in $x_j$ and $R^2_j$ is the R-squared from regressing $x_j$ on all the other independent variables(including the intercept).

I tried to compute the heteroskedasticity robust st.error in R studio, by appling the following:

\begin{equation}
 se(\hat{\beta}_j)= \frac{ \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \hat{u}_i^2 \hat{r}^2_{ij} }{n-k-1}}  }{ n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  (x_{ij} - \bar{x}_j)^2 (1-R^2_j)}
\end{equation}

However, I got a wrong heteroskedasticity robust st.error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wrong in comparison to what? Note that there are dozens of flavors of HAC standard errors.

Comment: I'm referring to the results in R coming from the lmtest and sandwich packages, with vcovHC(reg1, type = "HC0")

Comment: Does [the answer in this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/160897) help?

Comment: It looks like you divided the numerator by $\sqrt{n-k-1}$ and the denominator by $n$ in going from $\sqrt{\widehat{var}}[\hat\beta]$ to the se formula

Comment: Including a MWE would seem to be helpful here.